# How to unsubscribe using take operator?

Tags: angular, subscribe, unsubscribe, take

How can I unsubscribe from this using take operator?

```
constructor(/*params*/) {
  let id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
  if (id) this.productService.get(id).valueChanges().subscribe(p => this.product = p);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the `take(1)` operator to only fetch the value once, and complete the Observable right after, and with it unsubscribe all the subscriptions, you can do the following :

```
this.productService.get(id).valueChanges().pipe(
  take(1)
).subscribe(p => this.product = p)
```